# Linux java No such file or directory, java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, linux, filenotfoundexception, file-handling

While using the File reader in the Linux system(RHEL) the below statements are not able to locate the file, same cod is working fine in Windows env.

This code resists in one jar file which I cannot modify this is the snippet of the code

```
String fileInput = System.getProperty("filelocation");
BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileInput));
```

Attribute `"filelocation"` is passed as

```
"/home/admin/Downloads/tools/bin/configuration.txt"
```

or

```
"file:///home/admin/Downloads/tools/bin/configuration.txt"
```

Error log is

```
(No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/admin/Downloads/tools/bin/configuration.txt 
 (No such file or directory) 
       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) 
       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146) 
       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101) 
       at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58) 
       at com.mycode.Config.readAppConfig(config.java:123)
```

Comment: What does `System.out.println(new File("/home/admin/Downloads/tools/bin/configuration.txt").exists());` print?

Comment: Are you running the program as "admin"?

Comment: Its printing true, from my new program

Comment: Yes i am using admin account

Answer (score 0):

It was not related to JAVA. it was coming because of the shell script from where the variable was passed 
used the statement input_file=${input_file:0:$(expr ${#input_file} - 1) } 
this statement is used to remove the last character of a string, In my case it was a new Line char, which was not visible.

thanks to the form : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144298/delete-the-last-character-of-a-string-using-string-manipulation-in-shell-script/144345#144345?newreg=9e4833bcf644426aaf9f275bf4fd1743